# How to count number of rows in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that I need to read in PowerShell.

The last character in each row is either a Y or a N.

I need to go through the file and output how many Y's and N's are in there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23):

Assuming a file named "test.txt"...  To get the number of lines ending in Y, you can do this:

```
get-content test.txt | select-string Y$ | measure-object -line
```

And to get the number of lines ending in N, you can do this:

```
get-content test.txt | select-string N$ | measure-object -line
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: for any googlers that want this answer in a variable here it is

[code]
 $a = (Get-Content filename.txt| Select-String "|Y $" | Measure-Object).count
[/code]

Answer (score 7):

To get both the counts in a single line:

```
gc .\test.txt | %{ if($_ -match "Y$|N$"){ $matches[0]} } | group
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Get-Content test.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match '[YN]$'} | Group-Object {$_[-1]} -NoElement
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$lastchar = @{};get-content $file |% {$lastchar[$_[-1]]++};$lastchar
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer by @manojlds, so I'll throw something similar:

```
$grouped = (gc .\test.txt) -replace ".*(y|n)$",'$1' | group
```

(operators can be used on arrays as well).

Then you can use it like this:

```
($grouped | ? {$_.Name -eq 'y'}).count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(foreach ($line in [IO.File]::ReadAllLines(".\test.txt")) { 
    $line.Substring($line.Length - 1)
}) | Group
```