# How do I read in 1 column of problematic csv file to estimate number of rows?

Tags: r, data.table

So i have a csv file with the following format (2 double quotes as text qualifiers):

```
""hey you"",""run with me"",""school""
""Frank"",""separate"","",work""
```

`fread` from `data.table` is not able to read in this type of file. I still want to estimate the number of rows in this csv though. My initial solution was reading in just 1 column of data (the first column). This is the code I used:

```
d <- data.table::fread("file", select = c(1))
```

Unfortunately, the code still bombs out. Any solutions for getting the row numbers?

Comment: Now I don't want to read in the entire dataset. I just want to count the number of rows

Comment: Just use command line tools: `wc -l file`

Comment: Does this work in Powershell (Windows 7 x64)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936264/how-to-count-number-of-rows-in-powershell

Comment: You could also use `length(readLines(file))` in R but it will be substantially slower

Comment: To get the integer into R use: `data.table::fread("wc -l < file")$V1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting rows with fread without reading the whole file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691133/counting-rows-with-fread-without-reading-the-whole-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read in a csv with two double quotes as text qualifiers using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271928/how-do-i-read-in-a-csv-with-two-double-quotes-as-text-qualifiers-using-r)